# How do I write to cin, the input stream, in C++

Tags: c++, input, io

So I have a program (a game) designed to take input from a human via a keyboard.  It is desirable, however, that at certain points I take control away from the user and make certain decisions for them.  While it would be possible to write special-case code for use when events force the effects of user input to be emulated, I would much prefer to override the input stream (cin in this case) so that the program is in fact responding no different to forced decisions than had the user made such a decision of their own free will.

I have tried writing to it like I would an output stream (`cin<<'z'` for example) but the << operator isn't defined for cin and I don't know how to define it.

Would it be better to write to the keyboard buffer?  If so, how would I do that in a system agnostic manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing to the input is quite a hack. It would be *much* cleaner design to put an abstraction layer between the actual input (like `cin`) and the game acting on that input. Then, you could just reconfigure this abstraction layer to respond to procedurally generated commands instead of to `cin` whenever necessary.

Comment: So pull all input from cin into some buffer with custom functionality and then operate on that as the input stream for the program?  I'm afraid you aren't using 'abstraction layer' in a way I'm familiar with.  That does sound like it would work, though, so thanks!

Comment: @Lurker Yes, something like that. Or have an `InputSource` interface, one implementation for `cin`, one for "procedurally generated", and switch those when necessary - an abstraction over `cin`.

Comment: @Lurker It's called a decorator, at least if the abstraction simulates an `std::istream`.  (In fact, it's the streambuf used by `std::cin` that you want to decorate.)

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a streambuf into `std::cin`, something like:

```
class InjectedData : public std::streambuf
{
    std::istream* myOwner;
    std::streambuf* mySavedStreambuf;
    std::string myData;
public:
    InjectedData( std::istream& stream, std::string const& data )
        : myOwner( &stream )
        , mySavedStreambuf( stream.rdbuf() )
        , myData( data )
    {
        setg( myData.data(), myData.data(), myData.data() + myData.size() );
    }
    ~InjectedData()
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf(mySavedStreambuf);
    }
    int underflow() override
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf(mySavedStreambuf);
        return mySavedStreambuf->sgetc();
    }
};
```

(I've not tested this, so there may be errors.  But the basic
principle should work.)

Constructing an instance of this with `std::cin` as argument
will return characters from `data` until the instance is
destructed, or all of the characters have been consumed.

Comment: +1, sometimes showing the answer to the Y part of the X-Y problem is useful as well.

Comment: Very nice.  In particular this looks like it works well with strings of arbitrary (long) length as you can get out of the artificial input at any time.

Comment: @Lurker You can even temporarily switch the input to a file, if that's what you need; I've used something similar for handling macro expansion and include facilities, for example.  I've also used it for reformatting the input: stripping out comments, handling continuation lines, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would believe that writing to `cin` is the symptom of a badly designed program.

You probably in fact want to have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) which of course is operating system specific. On Posix and Linux, you could build it above the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) syscall, and you might want to set up a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) from your own process to itself.

Several libraries are providing some event loop: [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), and also frameworks like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/) ... (some of them are ported to several operating systems, so gives you an abstraction above the OS...)

Comment: actually, cin.putback(char) is a required part of the standard and was updated to work better in C++11 indicating it is still supported.  I do think adding an abstraction level is the best solution to my personal problem, but I see no reason why overriding an input stream would be a bad idea in general, and cin is no exception.